# How to invalidate NSTimer Which one running in loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want to play sound in different schedule like Every 3 , Every 5, after 9, after 22 ...etc, so I create a for loop and and pass different -2 scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval like this .

```
    -(void)bellsSchedual{

        arrBellsListAllData=[EMeditationDBModel getDataFromBellsList:prop.userId];
        EMeditationDBProperty *bellProp=[[EMeditationDBProperty alloc]init];
       for (int i=0; i<arrBellsListAllData.count; i++)
       {
        bellProp=[arrBellsListAllData objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *bellsTime=bellProp.bTime;
        if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"after"]) {

               bellTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:          [bellsTime intValue] target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats: NO];

}
  else if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"every"]){

        bellTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue] target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES]; 

        }
   }
}
```

problem is that my timer is not invalidate.if for loop run only once that time timer invalidate .

Comment: You only have a single `bellTimer` property, so you are going to lose the previous timer when you assign a new timer to this property.

Comment: yes  I have only one NSTimer Object and i assign different -2 scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval in same object which is wrong ?@Paulw11

Comment: Correct. Once you assign the second timer the first one will be released because there is no property retaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go with the approach of array of NSTimers

Somewhere, mostly in your viewDidLoad

```
NSMutableArray *arrTimers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

In your code

```
for (int i=0; i<arrBellsListAllData.count; i++)
{
    bellProp=[arrBellsListAllData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *bellsTime=bellProp.bTime;
    if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"after"]) {

         NSTimer *bellTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue] target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats: NO]

        [arrTimers addObject:bellTimer];
    }
    else if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"every"]){

         NSTimer *bellTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue] target: self
                                                         selector: @selector(playSound:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
         [arrTimers addObject:bellTimer]; 

    }
}
```

Invalidate by looping

```
-(void) invalidateAllTimers{
    for( NSTimer *timer in arrTimers) {
       [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

If you want to invalidate a particular timer then use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue]
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(playSound:)
                                           userInfo:anyId
                                            repeats:NO];
```

Where pass any identifier in userInfo object to find any specific timer.

Comment: and one more thinks like we start timer with every 5 sec but i want to pause facility in this example like sound is playing 60 , 55 ,50 45 but we pause timer on 52 sec after again we start then my timer is start again 48 ,43 .... so i want to is playing with old interval so if any idea how to solve this give me idea @iPrabu

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(void)bellsSchedual {

    arrBellsListAllData = [EMeditationDBModel getDataFromBellsList:prop.userId];
    EMeditationDBProperty *bellProp = [[EMeditationDBProperty alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<arrBellsListAllData.count; i++) {
        bellProp = [arrBellsListAllData objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *bellsTime = bellProp.bTime;
        if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"after"]) {
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue]
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(playSound:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        } else if ([bellProp.bTimeSchedule isEqualToString:@"every"]){
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[bellsTime intValue] target: self
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(playSound:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
        }
    }
}
```